# Integrability of derivative of $C_0^1(\mathbb{R})$ function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $C_0^1(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuously differentiable functions vanishing at infinity and $f\in C_0^1(\mathbb{R})$. Does this imply that the derivative $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb{R}$?

We have $\int_\mathbb{R}1_{[-n,n]}f'd\lambda=f(n)-f(-n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and $1_{[-n,n]}f'\to f'$ pointwise. However I don't see how this already implies integrability of $f'$. I thought about using dominated convergence but I don't have an integrable uniform bound for $|1_{[-n,n]}f'|$. Intuitively $f'$ should be integrable with integral $0$, I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Consider a function $f \in C_0^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} \to c$ for some $c > 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Then I don't think $f'$ can be integrable, because the tail decays too fast for either side to have a finite integral.

Comment: $\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\to c$ implies that $|f(x)|\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, I want $f$ to vanish at infinity.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $|xf(x)| \to c$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: $\sin(x)/x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I think I know this as a counterexample to the equivalence of improper Riemann integrability to Lebesgue integrability over $\mathbb{R}$. My takeaway from this is that the derivative $f'$ is improperly Riemann integrable (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$), however not Lebesgue. Does someone know a suitable criterion for Lebesgue integrability?

Comment: The answer seems to be that improper Riemann integrability of the absolute value of the derivative is equivalent to Lebesgue integrability over $\mathbb{R}$.